# Problema al Realizar Correlación ente Variables

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, pyspark

Estoy intentando realizar un análisis de correlación de variables. Para lo cual tengo la información en un RDD, lo convierto a DataFrame con Pandas. Me aseguro que todos los datos sean numéricos y finalmente realizo una matriz con su respectivo mapa de calor para encontrar su correlación. El código es el siguiente:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns

ctes = spark.read.parquet(path)
####################################################################################
################ Correlación de Variables Numéricas ################################
####################################################################################

# Lista de Variables Numéricas
var_num = ['n_reclamaciones', 'monto_total', 'n_tarjeta', 'fechas_op_dist','fechas_ini_dist','dist_fech_max',
'monto_promedio', 'dif_monto_max_min', 'dictamen_afavor_total', 'NO_CLAIMS_1_MONTH'
]

#Convertir a DF
tabal_aux = ctes[var_num].toPandas()

# ------------------Correlacion Spearman----------------------
tabla_corr = tabal_aux
#Cliclo para asegurar que todo tipo de datos sea numérico
for var in var_num:
    tabla_corr[var] = tabla_corr[var].astype(float)
corr = tabla_corr.corr(method = 'spearman')
plt.figure(figsize = (20,10))
sns.heatmap(corr, xticklabels = corr.columns.values, yticklabels = corr.columns.values, annot = True, linewidths = .6, cmap = 'Blues')
plt.tittle('Tabla de correlacioón Spearman')
plt.show()
plt.clf()

# ------------------Correlacion Pearson----------------------
tabla_corr = tabal_aux
for var in var_num:
    tabla_corr[var] = tabla_corr[var].astype(float)
corr = tabla_corr.corr(method = 'pearson')
plt.figure(figsize = (20,10))
sns.heatmap(corr, xticklabels = corr.columns.values, yticklabels = corr.columns.values, annot = True, linewidths = .6, cmap = 'Blues')
plt.tittle('Tabla de correlacioón Pearson')
plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

Sin embargo al ejecutar me aparece el siguiente error por consola (adjunto imagen):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les dejo la traza del error completa en formato código a continuación:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-38257abcbb84> in <module>()
     20            'MAX_LIMITE_CREDITO', 'MAX_PORC_ENDEUDAMIENTO', 'MIN_PORC_ENDEUDAMIENTO']
     21 # Convertir a df
---> 22 tabla_aux =  ctes[var_num].toPandas()
     23 # ----------------------------------------------- Correlación de Spearman -----------------------------------------------
     24 tabla_corr = tabla_aux
/opt/spark/dist/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in toPandas(self)
   1701         """
   1702         import pandas as pd
-> 1703         return pd.DataFrame.from_records(self.collect(), columns=self.columns)
   1704 
   1705     ##########################################################################################
/opt/spark/dist/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in collect(self)
    436         """
    437         with SCCallSiteSync(self._sc) as css:
--> 438             port = self._jdf.collectToPython()
    439         return list(_load_from_socket(port, BatchedSerializer(PickleSerializer())))
    440 
/opt/spark/dist/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:
/opt/spark/dist/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()
/opt/spark/dist/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o319.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 17 tasks (1060.8 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1516)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1503)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1503)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1731)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1686)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1675)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2051)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2072)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2091)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2116)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply$mcI$sp(Dataset.scala:2804)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2801)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2801)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2824)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:2801)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Entiendo por el error que me arroja que la conversión de RDD a DF no le gusta, o al menos es lo que interpreto. Podrían ayudarme orientándome en cual es mi problema en el código. De antemano gracias.

Comment: Por favor, podrías agregar la traza del error completa y en formato código, así será más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Listo, ya he añadido la traza completa del error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya pude lograr lo que necesitaba. Ósea la matriz de correlación. Añado el código con el que lo conseguí por si alguien se enfrenta en un futuro con un problema similar:

```
from pyspark.mllib.stat import Statistics
# Lista de variables numéricas
var_num = ['n_reclamaciones', 'monto_total', 'n_tarjeta', 'n_com', 'fechas_op_dist', 'fechas_inc_dist',
           'dist_fechas_max', 'monto_promedio', 'dif_monto_max_min', 'dictamen_afavor_total', 'NO_CLAIMS_1_MONTH',
          'NO_CLAIMS_3_MONTH', 'NO_CLAIMS_6_MONTH', 'NO_CLAIMS_12_MONTH', 'int_dias_prom', 'monto_1_mes',  'monto_3_mes',
          'monto_6_mes', 'monto_12_mes', 'num_fechas_aclaracion_dist', 'avg_claims_per_week','dif_monto_first_last',
          'div_comercio', 'edad', 'antiguedad',
          'pendiente', 'DISTINTAS_TARJETAS', 'DISTINTOS_GIROS', 'DISTINTAS_AFILIACIONES', 'NUMERO_TRANSACCIONES',
           'NUMERO_COMPRAS', 'NUMERO_RETIROS', 'MONTO_TRANSACCIONES', 'MONTO_COMPRAS', 'MONTO_RETIROS',
           'COMPRAS_CREDITO', 'COMPRAS_DEBITO', 'RETIROS_CREDITO', 'RETIROS_DEBITO', 'COMPRAS_MADRUGADA',
           'COMPRAS_MANANA', 'COMPRAS_TARDE', 'COMPRAS_NOCHE', 'RETIROS_MADRUGADA', 'RETIROS_MANANA',
           'RETIROS_TARDE', 'RETIROS_NOCHE', 'COMPRAS_ENTRE_SEMANA', 'COMPRAS_FIN_DE_SEMANA', 'RETIROS_ENTRE_SEMANA',
           'RETIROS_FIN_DE_SEMANA', 'COMPRAS_SUPERMERCADO', 'COMPRAS_AUTOS', 'COMPRAS_ENTRETENIMIENTO',
           'COMPRAS_VIAJES', 'COMPRAS_COMIDA', 'COMPRAS_ECOMMERCE', 'COMPRAS_TRANSPORTE', 'COMPRAS_ROPA_Y_CALZADO',
           'COMPRAS_EDUCACION', 'COMPRAS_DEPORTES', 'COMPRAS_TIENDAS_DEP', 'COMPRAS_SALUD', 'COMPRAS_CONSTRUCCION',
           'COMPRAS_PAGO_SERVICIOS', 'COMPRAS_MUEBLES_Y_OFICINAS', 'COMPRAS_BENEFICENCIA', 'COMPRAS_HOGAR',
           'COMPRAS_OTROS', 'MAX_CREDITO_DISPONIBLE', 'MAX_DEBITO_DISPONIBLE', 'MAX_SALDO_CREDITO',
           'MAX_LIMITE_CREDITO', 'MAX_PORC_ENDEUDAMIENTO', 'MIN_PORC_ENDEUDAMIENTO']
# Convertir a df
df =  ctes[var_num] 
def compute_correlation_matrix(df, method='pearson'):
    df_rdd = df.rdd.map(lambda row: row[0:])
    corr_mat = Statistics.corr(df_rdd, method=method)
    corr_mat_df = pd.DataFrame(corr_mat,
                    columns=df.columns,
                    index=df.columns)
    return corr_mat_df
compute_correlation_matrix(df)
```

Como salida me da la matriz de correlación de Pearson:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]